# Cordova cordova-plugin-device-motion plugin not calling callback

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, accelerometer

I used the Cordova CLI to create my project, added the plugin [cordova-plugin-device-motion](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion)
Then followed the simple tutorial to try and get values

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">-->
        <title>Rotations</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rotationHandler.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
            var watchID = null;

            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //
            //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onLoad() {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }
            
            // device APIs are available
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log('OGDEBUG onDeviceReady');
                startWatch();
            }

            // Start watching the acceleration
            //
            function startWatch() {
                // Update acceleration every 1 seconds
                var options = { frequency: 1000 };
                try{
                    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
                }catch(ex){
                    console.log('OGDEBUG startWatch error '+ex);
                }
                console.log('OGDEBUG startWatch');
            }

            // Stop watching the acceleration
            function stopWatch() {
                try{
                    if (watchID) {
                        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
                        watchID = null;
                    }
                }catch(ex){
                    console.log('OGDEBUG stopWatch error '+ex);
                }
                console.log('OGDEBUG stopWatch');
            }

            // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
            //
            function onSuccess(acceleration) {    
                var accelerationString = 
                        'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
                              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
                              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
                              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n';

                console.log('OGDEBUG onSuccess '+accelerationString);
            }

            // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
            //
            function onError() {
                alert('onError!');
                console.log('OGDEBUG onError' );
            }
            
            function buttonTapStart() {
                startWatch();
                console.log('OGDEBUG buttonTap (index)');
            }
            
            function buttonTapStop() {
                stopWatch();
                console.log('OGDEBUG buttonTap (index)');
            }
         </script>
    
        <div>
            <button onclick="buttonTapStart()">Start Watch</button>
            <button onclick="buttonTapStop()">Stop Watch</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

None of my catch/error log statements get called so it seems to be working (prior I have received `navigator` is undefined but moved stuff around and it seems to be good now).
My `onSuccess` callback is never called however, any ideas why?

FYI:

cordova.js and js/index.js are both generated files unedited and where created by the cli (for the specific platform)

Also take note, my `onDeviceReady` is never called either, but the Start Watch button does call `startWatch`

I am also using sensorsimulator-2.0-rc1 to fake the values of the accelerometer.  Regardless though (even if thats not working, though I have no reason to doubt that it does, and its own test work) I would think my onSuccess would be called with 0 values.

Comment: It appears that you are never calling `onLoad()` and if that event doesn't fire, no plugins will work. This is probably your issue. Try changing `<body>` to `<body onload="onLoad()">`

Comment: That did get onLoad() called so my startWatch method is called without the button needing to be clicked.  But onSuccess is still never called.

Comment: Are you testing on android or ios,or...?

Comment: android emulator (also take in mind like the notes say im using sensor simulator)

Comment: I agree with @DawsonLoudon. Your `onLoad()` is never called. Just use `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and it must work. I've tested your code on my real android device and it works.

Comment: the onload is called i see it in the logs.  but your "real" device might be the issue.  I have ran this on the browser and it does work.  its just the android emulator thats not working.  unfortunately my droid x doesnt have a new enough version of android to test with.  tried to load CyanogenMod but its currently stuck at the bootloader (need to work on it more).  either way though the sensorsimulator project seems to work on the android emulator so it should work on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after alot of troubleshooting and help from other forums I have found no way to successfully get this working.

However I did get my droid x to 4.4.4 and was able to test on it
and it works

so i have a solution for now (code works on a real device)